# Is there a more efficient way to combine/associate these 3 arrays?

Tags: php

I have three lists of keys and values separated by comma, resulted from a query in DB using `group_concat`, as follows:

JSON encoded hardware info:

```json
{  
   "2":"400",
   "4":"1500Mhz",
   "3":"GDDR5",
   "5":"12"
}
```

specifications keys:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

specifications values:

```
Lithography,# of Cores,# of Threads,Base Frequency,Cache
```

Here's how I did combine them:

```
$dbSpecs = array_combine(explode(',',$hwKeys),explode(',',$hwValues));
$hwspec = json_decode($info, true);
$combined = [];

foreach ($dbSpecs as $k => $v) {
    if(array_key_exists($k, $hwspec)){
      $combined[$v] = $hwspec[$k];
    }
}
```

I think keys and values can be stringified instead of using two columns in DB, but this is another story.

Is there a way to improve this piece of PHP?

Comment: Improve how? Do you want performance increase? More robust code? More readable code? Without stating that it's a rather broad question and will invite rater opinionated answers.

Comment: `array_merge` might be a good research point

Comment: @k0pernikus , more robust and readable I'd say. I thought this can be simplified somehow, but it's fine if it can be used in production as is.